# SQL I need the highest number from column + count duplicate values

Tags: sql, count, duplicates

I'm looking for a query that gives a list of the `RepairCost` for each `BikeNumber`, 
but the duplicate values have to be counted as well. So BikeNumber 18 cost total 22 + 58 = 80

```
Id      RepairCost  BikeNumber
16      82          23
88      51          20
12      20          19
33      22          **18**
40      58          **18**
69      41          17
10      2           16
66      35          15
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question, the query is pretty simple:

```
SELECT BikeNumber, SUM(RepairCost)
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY BikeNumber
```